# HTTPS Client with MKR1000

Tags: wifi, http

I am making an IoT device with the MKR1000.

As a part of the process, I would like to set up an HTTPS connection to https://hit.tl8.co/api/ping (this is a website I have made and control).

The problem is that `client.connect(url, 443)` is returning false. I have tried normal HTTP and the URL works on a browser. I can also access https://www.google.com. The code is a small variation of the example HTTP client.

As such, I believe that the TLS certificate I am using is not accessible by the MKR1000. Running this [report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=hit.tl8.co&s=2400%3a6180%3a0%3ad0%3a0%3a0%3a3e3%3a1&latest) shows that it is a RSA 2048 bits (e 65537) with SHA256withRSA certificate.

Is there a way to get the MKR1000 to accept this certificate? Failing that, what changes do I need to make to this certificate for it to work?

Is there a software solution to get this certificate working?

Comment: You need to use `connectSSL()` instead of `connect()`, and possibly add your certificate to the MKR1000 as described on [Hackster](http://hackster.io/arichetta/add-ssl-certificates-to-mkr1000-93c89d).